# Reshape dataframe from long to wide but amount of columns different for every row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe format in R

| question_id | answer_id | question_text | answer_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 0001 | how many people are alive? | 20000 |
| 10000 | 0002 | how many people are alive? | 50000 |
| 10000 | 0003 | how many people are alive? | 60000 |
| 10000 | 0004 | how many people are alive? | 900000 |
| 20000 | 0021 | what is the meaning of life? | yes |
| 20000 | 0072 | what is the meaning of life? | no |
| 20000 | 0083 | what is the meaning of life? | maybe |
| 20000 | 0094 | what is the meaning of life? | ok |
| 20000 | 0097 | what is the meaning of life? | indifference |

- Code for input data:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(question_id = c("10000", "10000", "10000", "10000", "20000", "20000", "20000", "20000", "20000"),
                  answer_id = c("0001", "0002", "0003", "0004", "0021", "0072", "0083", "0094", "0097"),
                  question_text = c("how many people are alive?", "how many people are alive?", "how many people are alive?", "how many people are alive?",
                                    "what is the meaning of life?", "what is the meaning of life?", "what is the meaning of life?", "what is the meaning of life?",
                                    "what is the meaning of life?"),
                  answer_text = c("20000", "50000", "60000", "900000", "yes", "no", "maybe", "ok", "indifference"))
```

I want it in the following format:

| question_id | question_text | answer_text_1 | answer_text_2 | answer_text_3 | answer_text_4 | ... | answer_text_n |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | how many people are alive? | 20000 | 50000 | 60000 | 900000 | ... | NA |
| 20000 | what is the meaning of life? | yes | no | maybe | ok | ... | indifference |

So as you can see I want the question_id, then the question_text itself and then a set of column which equal to the maximum amount of answers there can be to a question. So some questions are true or false so would only have 2 columns filled in. But also multiple choice questions can exist, which might have 7 different options to choose from. I want it to be adaptive.

The only thing I could think of was `tidyr::pivot_wider()`. I can't seem to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

========== edit ===========

the code that I tried

```
qa_columns <- function(qa_df, question_list){
  df <- qa_df %>%
    dplyr::filter(question_id %in% question_list) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(values_from = answer_text)
  return(df)
}

qa <- qa_columns(qa_text, question_list = question_list)
```

Comment: Please show the code that you cannot get to work, including the output (if any) and why it is wrong.

Comment: I added the code! Does it make sense like this? Can explain further if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a row-number per group, then keeping `question_text` as an id:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
dat %>%
  group_by(question_id) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(c("question_id", "question_text"), names_from = "rn", names_prefix = "answer_text_", values_from = "answer_text")
# # A tibble: 2 x 7
#   question_id question_text                answer_text_1 answer_text_2 answer_text_3 answer_text_4 answer_text_5
#         <int> <chr>                        <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        
# 1       10000 how many people are alive?   20000         50000         60000         900000        <NA>         
# 2       20000 what is the meaning of life? yes           no            maybe         ok            indifference
```

Note that this coerces numbers to `character` in your `answer_text_#` columns, generally unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(dat), question_id + question_text ~ 
   paste0("answer_text_", rowid(question_id)), value.var = "answer_text")
```

-output

```
 question_id                question_text answer_text_1 answer_text_2 answer_text_3 answer_text_4 answer_text_5
1:       10000   how many people are alive?         20000         50000         60000        900000          <NA>
2:       20000 what is the meaning of life?           yes            no         maybe            ok  indifference
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(question_id = c(10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 
20000L, 20000L, 20000L, 20000L, 20000L), answer_id = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 21L, 72L, 83L, 94L, 97L), question_text = c("how many people are alive?", 
"how many people are alive?", "how many people are alive?", "how many people are alive?", 
"what is the meaning of life?", "what is the meaning of life?", 
"what is the meaning of life?", "what is the meaning of life?", 
"what is the meaning of life?"), answer_text = c("20000", "50000", 
"60000", "900000", "yes", "no", "maybe", "ok", "indifference"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```